# Match String with Number Placeholder

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to match the following strings: With String match: https://apidock.com/ruby/String/match

```
"The account 340394034 is finalized"

"The account 9394834 is finalized"

"The account 12392039483 is finalized"

"The account 3493849384 is finalized"

"The account 32984938434983 is finalized"
```

**Which regex do I have to use to match this strings with number placeholders in it?** Thanks

`"The account {number_placeholder} is finalized"`

Comment: Any attempt? Seems trivial.

Comment: Hmmmmmmm `\d+`?

Comment: @ctwheels can you please show an full example

Comment: @JohnSmith Actually `\d+` is the full regexp!

Comment: Honestly, depending on the input, that might very well be the full example. It matches all your examples

Comment: Thanks yes it works, please write it as an answer, so that I can rate it as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to use the `match` method to determine whether a given string matches the pattern in your examples, you can do this:

```
example = "The account 32984938434983 is finalized"

if example.match(/The account \d+ is finalized/)
  puts "it matched"
else
  puts "it didn't match"
end
```

The match method returns a `MatchData` object (basically the part of the string that matched the regex, which in this case is the whole thing). Using it on a non-matching string will return `nil`, this means you can use the result of the match method for if-statements.

If you want to extract the number in the string, only if the string matches the pattern, you could do this:

```
example = "The account 32984938434983 is finalized"
match_result = example.match(/The account (\d+) is finalized/)

number = if match_result
           match_result.captures.first.to_i
         else
           number = nil # or 0 / some other default value
         end
```

The brackets in the regex form a "capture group". The `captures` method on the result gives an array of all the capture group matches. The `first` method gets the first (and in this case only) element from that array, and the `to_i` method converts the string into an integer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the full regex

```
\d+
```

Depending on input, assuming there is a possibility of other numbers in the string, you could use this instead and get the contents of capture group 1:

```
account\s+(\d+)
```